# how to open vs 2008 solution in vs2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, projects-and-solutions

Please help me how can I open Visual Studio 2008 solution in Visual Studio 2010 and what changes I have to do here in web.config file.

```
<add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
```

It is showing error in this line when I run the solution in VS2010

Comment: Is the error showing up the conversion report or once you actually open the converted solution in vs2010? Also - note that crystal reports is an add-on for vs2010

Comment: "It is showing error in this line" - *what* error is it showing? Error messages frequently contain useful information.